# php script using too much memory and returning fatal error

Tags: php, html, debugging, out-of-memory

I am getting the following message

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
> to allocate 528384 bytes) in
> /home/u234536193/domains/monetizingonline.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php
> on line 2024

The code on line 2024 is:

```
$this->result = mysqli_query( $this->dbh, $query );
```

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: You need to fetch less data. e.g. use `WHERE` or `LIMIT` to fetch fewer records. It is also possible you have a memory leak, but we can't tell you without seeing the code.

Comment: I am fairly new to wordpress - What part of the code would you need?

Comment: OP was here before but deleted his previous post, it appears. OP does not have original source but instead code generated from some theme site, I forget the name of which now. OP should have lead with that information here but since he didn't, I am doing the FYI.

Comment: I should also add, OP's previous post was "closed" by moderator due to not having enough debugging details and no posted code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT` clause to limit the data querying. Or implement something similar to Pagination.

You can:

- Query the results in with a Limit.
- And add a button to query the next set of results from the last id of previous query.

Comment: I have increase the memory limit to 512mb as a temporary fix and it was working fine. But now again I am getting - Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 548864 bytes) in /home/u234536193/domains/monetizingonline.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1989  the code in line 1989 is -  while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_object( $this->result ) ) { I am fairly new to wordpress too, any simplified suggestions?

Comment: If I limit the data query will that affect the fuctionality of the site i.e will I not keep getting the fatal error?